# replace Statement to insert into specific columns only

Tags: android, sqlite, replace, insert

I am trying to use replace statement but only to replace data in specific columns, but the query i am using is replacing values in all the columns.

```
public boolean insertDataTable(String FileNumber, String Areas, String Level, String ProjectCode, String Year, String Department, String University, String Address, String City, String State, String Region, String UserId) {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = " REPLACE INTO DataTable (FileNumber, Areas, Level, ProjectCode, Year, Department, University, Address, City, State, Region, UserId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query,new String[]{FileNumber, Areas, Level, ProjectCode, Year, Department, University, Address, City, State, Region, UserId});
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return true;
    }
```

I have table with 13 columns, i am trying to not update value in last column. this is the code i am using.

Comment: Are you aware of https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html ? Please explain why you cannot use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch Update was giving me the same result as REPLACE, But I used INSERT and specified the column names and values. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you misunderstood the purpose of the [`REPLACE`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/) statement. 
It is not the same as `UPDATE`. 
Read the above link and you will see that `REPLACE`:

> inserts a new row or deletes the row that conflicts with the new row
>   and then adds the new row.

I believe what you really want is to update a row in the table. So do this:

```
String query = "UPDATE DataTable SET " + 
"FileNumber = ?, Areas = ?, Level = ?, ProjectCode = ?, Year = ?, Department = ?, " +
"University = ?, Address = ?, City = ?, State = ?, Region = ?, UserId = ? " +
"WHERE ......";
```

Use the `WHERE` clause at the end of the statement to specify which row to update, otherwise all the rows of the table will be updated.

Comment: Thank you @forpas I was not able to do it because I was inserting values in an empty table so I couldn't use where clause. 
But I solved the issue with INSERT command and specified the column name and values.

Comment: Rishabh Shukla, this does not sound like this answer really solved your problem, so why did you accept it? (Sorry forpas, I don't begrudge you the rep, but it seems that OP misunderstands the meaning of accepting.) If your solution is noticable different from this, then consider making an answer yourself.